# How to call multiple methods in a class when using multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading

So I'm new to Python and I'm learning about multi threading. I watched a video on how to do it and followed. I got this:

```
from threading import *

from time import sleep

class Hello(Thread):

    def run(self):
        for i in range(5):
            print("Hello")
            sleep(1)

class Hi(Thread):

    def run(self):
        for i in range(5):
            print("Hi")
            sleep(1)

t1 = Hello()

t2 = Hi()

t1.start()

sleep(0.2)

t2.start()
```

Which prints Hello and Hi simultaneously. But I'm confused about the start used in t1.start() and t2.start() because the classes Hello and Hi don't have a start method. What if I have different methods with different names, how can I call them? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: They inherited the `start` method from the `Thread` class which you specified as a base class.

Comment: You call different methods by using their names. I'm not sure what is unclear to you about that.

Comment: No like lets say I have 2 methods one is run(self) and the other another thing (self), how do I call the other one since you said that the start method is in the Thread class.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you tried to do which was not working? I think you are just worrying about a problem that does not exist.

Comment: lets say I want to print hi hello name hi hello name ......... for 5 times just using the Hi and Hello classes. I want to add another method into Hi which prints name 5 times. What do I call that method because I can't call it run because there's already a method called run. Sorry if this is a really simple concept but I just started Python this week and  I can't seem to get this. Thank you @mkrieger1

Comment: You can give the method any name you want. To have it executed, it must be called inside `run`.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of points:

(1) A `Hello` instance *is* a `Thread` instance. You wrote, `class Hello(Thread): ...`. That declares your `Hello` class to be a specialization of the `Thread` class. Your `Hello` object has a `start()` method because the `Thread` class has a `start()` method.

(2) A `Thread` instance is not a *thread*. A *thread* is an operating system object. A `Thread` instance is a "handle" that your program uses to create and interact with an operating system *thread*. The `t1.start()` call is where the new *thread* gets created.

(3) After a new thread is created by `t1.start()`, it will call `t1.run()`. That's carved in stone. You can't change it, BUT...

(4) ...*You* write the `run()` method yourself. It will do whatever you make it do. If you want the thread to call some `self.foobar()` method, then all you have to do is put a call to `self.foobar()` inside your `run()` method.